# How to change the plot area size to fit labels? some labels are cut at the graph margin

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

```
ggplot(data=df_qtr, aes(x=trip_qtr,y=trip_count), width=20)+
geom_line(aes(group=customer_type, color=customer_type))+
geom_point()+
scale_x_continuous(labels=c('Q1_2022', 'Q2_2022', 'Q3_2022', 'Q4_2022'))+
geom_text(aes(label = label_comma(accuracy=NULL)(trip_count)), vjust=-1.5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tLPw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HihHv.png)

when I use theme(aspect.ratio=2) or theme(aspect.ratio=2), the size changes in corresponding proportion but the labels still do not fit..

the second method I used below was promising, however, it changed the x_axis label from 1 to 5:

```
ggplot(data=df_qtr, aes(x=trip_qtr,y=trip_count), width=20)+
geom_line(aes(group=customer_type, color=customer_type))+
geom_point()+
scale_x_continuous(labels=c('Q1_2022', 'Q2_2022', 'Q3_2022', 'Q4_2022'))+
geom_text(aes(label = label_comma(accuracy=NULL)(trip_count)), vjust=-1.5)+
xlim(c(min(df_qtr$trip_qtr) - 1,max(df_qtr$trip_qtr) + 1))`
```

Comment: Try with `+ coord_cartesian(clip = "off)`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.